# Need help in setting up CI/CD - Selenium Grid - Java- Docker

Tags: maven, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, selenium-grid

I'm new to gitlab CI/CD.

I want to set-up my Selenium tests to run whenever a code is checked in gitlab.

The selenium tests are written in Java - and it is a Maven project.

Also, the selenium Grid is being used in docker for parallel testing.

I've also set up gitlab runner in docker.

I registered the runner to the gitlab repository where my selenium project is. when I'm running the tests, it pick up the correct runner, but I'm not sure on how to execute the maven project and make it run against the selenium-grid.

Note: my project is working fine locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that I will have to install the maven image to the gitlab-runner docker like this

image: maven:3-jdk-11

test-job1:

stage: test

tags:

```
- selenium
```

script:

```
- mvn install
```

This worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

The process is similar to what you are doing locally.

The only thing you have to make sure of is that the grid is accessible in the runner container from where the execution is happening. For running the maven command, ensure your runner container has required tools like JDK and maven installed and appropriate environment variables like JAVA_HOME, etc.., are setup.